# Powershell core to powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

I'm running an Ubuntu EC2 instance with Pwsh installed to remote execute AD commands on one of our servers. 2sd hop is set-up correctly and i'm able to run AD commands but when executing my script i get the following error (Scripts works fine directly on the 2sd hop machine):

> The search filter cannot be recognized
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException                                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
>   + PSComputerName        : corpmaint02

```
#!/usr/bin/pwsh
$employeeEmail = 'myemail@contoso.com'
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName corpmaint02 -ConfigurationName corpmaint02 -Credential contoso\myadminaccount
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $employeeEmail -ScriptBlock{
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$employeeEmail'" -Properties EmailAddress | Disable-ADAccount
Write-Host $employeeEmail has been 'disabled.'
}
Remove-PSSession -ID $session.ID
[GC]::Collect()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/pwsh
$cred=Get-Credential domain\myadmin
$employeeEmail = 'myemail@contoso.com'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName corpmaint02 -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName corpmaint02 -Authentication Negotiate  -ArgumentList $employeeEmail -$
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($Args[0])'" -Properties EmailAddress | Disable-ADAccount -verbose
Write-Host $employeeEmail has been 'disabled.'
}
I modified my code as follow and it works expect for the lack of permissions to disable the account which odd because my admin account has rights to do so.
```

> Insufficient access rights to perform the operation
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=xxxxx\domain,DC=com:ADUser) [Disable-ADAccount], ADException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.DisableADAccount
>   + PSComputerName        : corpmaint02

New code to elevate:

```
#!/usr/bin/pwsh
$cred=Get-Credential domain\myadmin
$employeeEmail = 'user1@contoso.com' 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName corpmaint02 -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName corpmaint02 -Authentication Negotiate -ArgumentList $employeeEmail,$cred -ScriptBlock{
$currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$testadmin = $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
    if ($testadmin -eq $false) {
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($Args[0])'" -Properties EmailAddress | Disable-ADAccount -verbose -Credential $Args[1]
}
Write-Host $employeeEmail 'has been disabled.'
```

Comment: Did you try using the `using` scope modifier on `$employeeEmail`?  Take a look at 'Example 9' in the [Invoke-Command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) to see what I mean.

Comment: Either use `using`, or declare `param($employeeEmail)` at the start of the remote scriptblock

Comment: Yes, using: or param(.  It isn't well documented.

Comment: Using arrays with param( is another layer of difficulty.

Comment: New code in edits works but i face permission issues even if my admin account has rights to disable accounts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Command isn't running with elevated rights, so you can retrieve data but not make changes.

https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html
*If you use Invoke-Command to run a script or command on a remote computer, then it will not run elevated even if the local session is. This is because any prompt for elevation will happen on the remote machine in a non-interactive session and so will fail.*

You can try self elevating in the Invoke-Command scriptblock (from the link above)

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
{
  # Relaunch as an elevated process:
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-File",('"{0}"' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb RunAs
  exit
}
# Now running elevated so launch the script:
& "d:\long path name\script name.ps1" "Long Argument 1" "Long Argument 2"
```

Comment: No changes in the output error:(New code attached in the main thread)

+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (corpmaint02:String) [],PSCryptoException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken